# Serialization.Runtime.Exception: End of stream encountered before parsing was completed

Tags: serialization

For almost a week I am trying to resolve an issue in my code!
I want to deserialize a stream data (of size 400 MB) by dividing the stream data into smaller size stream data. When I try to do that, I get the serialization exception : end of stream encountered before parsing was completed.
Here are my steps:
 1. Read stream data in a byte array data
 2. Divide the byte array data into smaller byte array data
 3. Convert the smaller byte arrays into smaller streams
 4. Deserialize each smaller stream data and combine the output.

I printed out the position of the stream data before deserialization and it was 0.
Please let me know in solving my code! Thank you!
My C# code:

enter code here

```
public static T DeserializeBuffer<T>(Stream A)
{
   List<Pulse> output = new List<Pulse>();//// Pulse is a class. I am deserializing the stream data as an object of Pulse. 
   byte[] bufferdata1 = new byte[4096]; /// 4 KB size data.
   int t1 = A.Read(bufferdata1, 0, bufferdata1.Length); //// reading data into bufferdata1
   Stream s1 = new MemoryStream(bufferdata1); /// smaller size stream data s1
   Console.WriteLine(s1.Position); /// position of stream s1
   BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
   return(T)bf.Deserialize(s1); //// deserialization of s1
}
```

Comment: You can't chop up the data stream like that. There is no way to tell whereabouts in your 400MBytes the boundaries are between the bytes that represent single objects. So if you chop up the 400MByte at arbitrary locations, you're almost certainly spreading the bytes for one object between two smaller streams. Hence the exception. The only thing to do is to get whatever generates the 400MB to serialise batches of `Pulse`s to separate data files which can then be deserialised separately.

Comment: Thank you bazza! In order to do it in batches of Pulse file, don't we have to know the position of different pulse data in the stream data?